# ClassNotFoundException while using coordinator layout with firebase

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I am getting `RuntimeException`, `InflateException`, `ClassNotFoundException`.

my `build.gradle` have

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"
```

and `Logcat log` is

```
Process: com.nikhil.firebase, PID: 10511
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nikhil.firebase/com.nikhil.firebase.SignUpActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
     at com.nikhil.firebase.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:29)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.nikhil.firebase.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:29) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nikhil.firebase-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nikhil.firebase-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.nikhil.firebase.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:29) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.1_6a41e66d0de39617155341541059c34ffee72147-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikhil.firebase/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.nikh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this dependency. It should work after you add it and do clean build :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

Please let me know if it changes anything for you.